# Could someone explain to me why this button click is triggering when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a page that loads results from an external PHP script and then dynamically adds buttons which when clicked takes you to the other pages. I 
figured I'd do this via a `for` loop that gets the number of pages from the PHP file (which I've omitted).

I have an additional function called `test(pageNum)` that takes in a page number parameter and gets the results and displays them in the table. That functions fine but whenever I load the page it seems to call the button click functions immediately. Could someone explain the issue here please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  test(1);

  $.get("link here", {
    op: "pages"
  }, function(data) {
    $("h1").html(data);
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
      (function() {
        var btn = $("<button>/", {
          type: 'button',
          text: j,
          on: {
            click: test(j)
          }
        });
        $('#buttons').append(btn);
      })(j);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is because you're passing the *result* of `test(j)` to the `cilck` handler, not a function reference as you should be. Try `click: function() { test(j); }`. You can also avoid the need for the closure if you read the `text` (or better still a `data` attribute) from the clicked `button` element

Comment: Your only function is `$(document).ready`

Comment: You don't have to add click event to all the buttons that you appended. Give it a class. And use on delegated click event to fire click for that element

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
on: {  click: test(j) }
```

sets your `click` event to the *result* of `test(j)` - ie calls it immediately.

Change this to

```
on: { click: function() { test(j) } }
```